# How to capture elements with only one component as dynamic in xpath

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I need to capture all the elements using "findelements" that has the xpath as below, where X can be random numbers like 1,2,3 etc. Except X rest of the Xpath remains constant.

```
//*[@id='cobCustPgmEditTreePopup']/div[4]/div[3]/div/div[X]/div/span[2]
```

Please help with solutions on how can I do this?

Comment: Please show the code you have tried, and explain what problems you have encountered.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't specify the index in the first place:

```
//*[@id='cobCustPgmEditTreePopup']/div[4]/div[3]/div/div/div/span[2]
```

Comment: $List<WebElement> test=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='cobCustPgmEditTreePopup']/div[4]/div[3]/div/div/div/span[2]"));

Comment: Please ignore the previous comment.                                   'List<WebElement> test=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='cobCustPgmEditTreePopup']/div[4]/div[3]/div/div/div/span[2]"));'       But the result was some junk values.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do it like below

x = randomNumber // say 1,2,3,4......

```
//your xpath 
//*[@id='cobCustPgmEditTreePopup']/div[4]/div[3]/div/div[X]/div/span[2]

just brake ur xpath in two parts 

String myfirstXpath = "//*[@id='cobCustPgmEditTreePopup']/div[4]/div[3]/div/div[";
String mysecondXpath = "]/div/span[2]";

driver.findElement(By.xpath(myfirstXpath + X + mysecondXpath)).click(); // any action you want
```

Hope this helps what you are looking for.

Comment: Value of X can be any random numbers. So I cannot pass values for X. What I was trying,  is to find out all the elements in that web page with this xpath pattern by keeping X as variable.

Comment: do not confuse X can have any random numbers form 0 to max and still in the above solution u can pass it as an variable .if still it dosen't make sense to you then please elaborate your question including a scenario so that any body can understand what are you looking for